# Why do Vengeance Paladins get Banishment twice?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, paladin

Typo perhaps?  They released an Errata for the 5E PHB but this was not touched on.

In the Paladin Spell lists (PHB, p. 209), the spell *Banishment* is listed at 4th level for all Paladins.

On page 88 of the PHB dealing with the Vengeance Oath, one of the three Oath specialties a Paladin can choose, the bonus spell list for level 13 (when you get your first 4th level spell slot) includes Banishment again.  Is this redundant, to get from a specialty the same spell that the base class grants to begin with?  I'm confused.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Being on the Paladin spell list means that the spell is available, and the Paladin can prepare this spell.

Since Banishment is an oath spell, Vengeance Paladins always have this spell prepared. Refer the Oath Spells section on page 85:

> ... Once you gain access to an oath spell, you always have it prepared. Oath spells don't count against the number of spells you can prepare each day

It is not a typo or mistake. It just means that, while all Paladins can prepare it, Vengeance Paladins *always* have Banishment prepared from level 13 onwards.

Comment: I had to scratch my head a little at first too when I saw this in PHB. It's a bit of a recurring theme in the class descriptions though. Keeps things nicely streamlined IMO.

Comment: Do you mean from level 3 on?

Comment: No, they can't prepare banishment at level 3, since they do not have the spell slots to cast it.